# Suggestions for 1-5 km range wireless communication?

Tags: wireless, wifi, xbee

I am developing a VOIP application. Most clients use a wired Ethernet connection, but some of the clients need to have a wireless connection. Currently the core board is using:

- Cortex-A8 ([TI AM3359](http://www.ti.com/product/am3359))
- 256MB RAM
- 2GB Flash
- WiFi 802.11N

But the range of WiFi is very terrible, compared to ~5Km walkie talkie, I know [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) might work but I have never used it in either production or development. My requirements for the digital wireless communication are:

1. 1-5Km in Range (1Km with minor obstacles or 5Km line of sight)
2. 100Kbps (12.5KB/s) lowest transfer rate condition.
3. multiple clients (100 clients)
4. relatively low price.
5. preferably: support TCP/IP, support simple encryption (so no need to modify software stack much)

So should I use XBee? or any other alternatives? Thanks.

Comment: I have required 5pcs of wirless range 1.5km

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Xbee modules** are an option, as are other 800 to 900 Mhz RF modules, but subject to some constraints.

I suggest you make your choice by looking at [Digi's comparison matrix table](http://www.digi.com/pdf/chart_xbee_rf_features.pdf) of the different Xbee options; there are at least three that suit your application, and they are point-to-multipoint capable.

The table states you can get outdoor range **up to 40 km** (for example, with the XBee-PRO 868), but note a couple of things:

- this is outdoors range; if the same transmission were attempted in an indoors environment (or generally a situation where there are intererence sources within the Fresnel zone), your range will drop **markedly**.
- this requires using a high-gain antenna, so that may be a constraint depending on what your device construction allows (in fact, I think most of the distances specified in that table are with a dipole antenna).
- some of the model variants are only available selectively in Europe or North America, if this matters.
- for some insight on performance metrics, it's worth reading [this app note](http://www.digi.com/pdf/wp_xbeepro868range.pdf), where they demonstrate nearly 0% packet loss at distances up to 40 km range, but with specific conditions.

Note that the data rate for the long-range models might not meet your requirement of 100 Kbps, which is a tough ask although...

Alternately, **GSM modules** perform your bandwidth requirement easily in a different context, which brings up an alternate idea: You can also consider instead using [GSM modules](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9533) for your communication, although this obviously might turn pricey since you state there are on the order of a 100 users.

One final suggestion is to use the low- or medium-range Xbee models, but use extenders/repeaters/relay-units to cover the required distance (or in case of the Zigbee variant of Xbee, you can even use the units in the mesh as extenders themselves). Setting up a robust Zigbee network takes some development effort, but this is somewhat simplified with the firmware stack on the Xbee ZB units.